Describing the functor of point of a quotient stack
A few friends and I have been reading Adeel A. Khan lecture notes on algebraic stacks (which you can find here https://www.preschema.com/papers/stacksncts.pdf) and we came across a problem with his theorem 4.4.4 which is the following :

Given $G_\bullet$ a group stack over a scheme $S$ and $U$ a stack with a $G$-action, the quotient stack $[U/G]$ is the geometric realization $\lim_{[n]\in\Delta} U_n$ taken in $Stk$. 
Theorem 4.4.4: 
For every $S$-scheme $T$, there is a functorial equivalence of groupoids between $[U/G](T)$ and the groupoids of diagrams $$T\overset{\pi}{\leftarrow} Y \overset{f}{\rightarrow}U$$ where $\pi$ is a $G$-torsor over $Y$ and $f:Y\rightarrow U$ is a $G$-equivariant $S$-morphism. An isomorphism $\phi : Y \rightarrow Y'$ in this groupoid is a $G$-equivariant isomorphism compatible with $\pi,\pi'$ and $f,f'$ 

The construction is essentially the following: by Yoneda's lemma, $[U/G](T)$ is the groupoid of morphisms $T\rightarrow [U/G]$. Any such morphism gives rise to $Y=T\times_{[U/G]} U$ with maps $f:Y\rightarrow U$ and $G$-torsor $Y\rightarrow T$. 
In the other way, such a diagram gives rise to a morphism $T\simeq [Y/G] = |Y_\bullet| \overset{|f_\bullet|}{\rightarrow} |U_\bullet| = [U/G]$. 

It is not hard to see that starting from a morphism $T\rightarrow [U/G]$ and applying the above construction in both direction we recover functorially what we started from. 

My question is the following: starting from a diagram $$T\overset{\pi}{\leftarrow} Y \overset{f}{\rightarrow}U$$ why do we have an ($G$-equivariant) isomorphism $T\times_{[U/G]} U \rightarrow  Y$, which is functorial in $Y$? That is, why is it an equivalence of category in that direction ?  This is left as an exercise in multiple sources so I didn't find anything online so far.

So far I know that we have such a map $\phi : Y  \rightarrow  T\times_{[U/G]} U$ by the universal property of the product, so by Lurie's theorem (4.1.9 in the above paper) $\phi$ induces a map between the Cech nerves of $pr_1 :T\times_{[U/G]} U \rightarrow  T$ and $\pi : Y \rightarrow T$ thus between their action groupoids object since they are $G$-torsors (via the canonical map).  Now I'd like to show that this groupoid object map $\phi$ is an isomorphism, which would conclude since I know is that it is $G$-equivariant, but I can't really see why.

The universal map is $\varphi\colon Y\to T\times_{[U/G]} U$, not the other way around. It suffices to show that $\varphi_0\colon Y_0\to T\times_{[U/G]}U_0$ is an equivalence, i.e. that
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y_0 @>>> U_0\\
@VVV @VVV\\
T @>>> [U/G]
\end{CD}
$$
is a pullback diagram. By pullback pasting, we may as well suppose that the right vertical map is the universal $G$-torsor $*\to BG$ with a terminal object as domain. Now, pullback along effective epimorphisms is a conservative functor when we work inside an $(n,1)$-topos (this is a corollary of the theorem of Lurie that you mentioned), so we may pull back along $Y_0\to T$ and show that the map $$Y_0\times_T Y_0\to Y_0\times_{BG}*\simeq Y_0\times(*\times_{BG}*)$$ is an equivalence. Now, since $Y_0\to T$ and $*\to BG$ are $G$-torsors, this map is actually just homotopic to the identity morphism on $Y_0\times G_1$, so is indeed an equivalence.

Hi Daniël, thank you for the answer. I want to be sure, your last point that it is homotopic to the identity, because it is the identity on Y_0 because this is a pullback and on G_1 by G-equivariance ?

Yes, that's indeed the reason.
